# Deploying worklight project on WAS 8.5

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I got the following exception when i deployed the war on WAS 8.5

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'identityAssociationCleanupTask' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: "WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.57.82 {prepstmnt -234009374 SELECT t0.HOSTVMID, t0.ID, t0.UPDATETIMESTAMP, t0.VERSION FROM WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC t0 WHERE t0.ID = ?  optimize for 1 row [params=(String) identityAssociationCleanupTask]} [code=-204, state=42704]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=SQLNQ1FC, Errd=-2145779603, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0]
"WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.57.82
An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-204", SQLSTATE "42704" and message tokens "WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=3.57.82
An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-204", SQLSTATE "42704" and message tokens "WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=3.57.82; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: "WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.57.82 {prepstmnt -234009374 SELECT t0.HOSTVMID, t0.ID, t0.UPDATETIMESTAMP, t0.VERSION FROM WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC t0 WHERE t0.ID = ?  optimize for 1 row [params=(String) identityAssociationCleanupTask]} [code=-204, state=42704]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=SQLNQ1FC, Errd=-2145779603, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0]
"WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.57.82
An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-204", SQLSTATE "42704" and message tokens "WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=3.57.82
An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-204", SQLSTATE "42704" and message tokens "WRKSCHM.CLUSTER_SYNC".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=3.57.82
```

But I am able to deploy the same on the embedded server of eclipse.
And iam not able to see any internal tables under APPCNTR database.

Iam using worklight 6.0 and i installed using installation manager 1.6.3.
Iam using DB2 10.1,I have manually created APPCNTR,WRKLGHT,WLREPORT databases and set the schemas for WRKLGHT as WRKSCHM and WLREPORT as WLRESCHM.
I followed this http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdeploy%2Fc_deploy_custom_war_file_to_app_server.html, for Configuring WebSphere Application Server for DB2 manually.
followed http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdeploy%2Fc_deploy_custom_war_file_to_app_server.html this to Configuring WebSphere Application Server manually and deploying .
Please help me if I have missed any configuration.

Comment: This looks like a configuration issue. It would be helpful if you provide more information, such as your Worklight version and the steps you followed. There is a Getting Started module that explains the steps to move from a development environment to stand-alone QA and production servers. Did you go through these steps? Here's the module for Worklight 6.1: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/10_01_Moving_from_development_environment_to_stand-alone_QA_and_production_servers.pdf

Comment: From this page you can also find Getting Started modules for previous versions of Worklight: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided details about your environment (Worklight version, WAS profile, database) so it is difficult to pinpoint exactly what the problem could be; my answer is based on certain assumptions, such as that you are using DB2.

Looking closely to the error:

- **WRKSCHM** is the schema name that Worklight Server is trying to access through JPA
- **CLUSTER_SYNC** is a table in the 'WRKLGHT' database

This error can be caused by either the table not being properly created (DB2 setup process is incomplete), or by a schema name mismatch (WAS datasource setup incorrect).

Please verify the following on your environment:

**DB2 Setup**
Make sure that your DB2 is properly configured for Worklight; verify that the necessary databases are created ('WRKLGHT' for Worklight Server, 'WLREPORT' for the Worklight Reports feature and 'APPCNTR' for Worklight Application Center). The following documentation might be useful to you:

- [Creating the DB2 databases](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_creating_the_db2_databases.html&resultof=%2522%2557%254c%2552%2545%2550%254f%2552%2554%2522%2520%2522%2577%256c%2572%2565%2570%256f%2572%2574%2522%2520)
- [Setting up the 'WRKLGHT' and 'WLREPORT' databases](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_setting_up_your_db2_database_manually.html&resultof=%2522%2557%2552%254b%2553%2543%2548%254d%2522%2520%2522%2577%2572%256b%2573%2563%2568%256d%2522%2520)
- [Setting up the 'APPCNTR' database](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_setting_up_your_db2_database_manually_for_ac.html&resultof=%2522%2561%2570%2570%2563%2565%256e%2574%2565%2572%2522%2520%2522%2561%2570%2570%2563%2565%256e%2574%2522%2520%2522%2564%2561%2574%2561%2562%2561%2573%2565%2522%2520%2522%2564%2561%2574%2561%2562%2561%2573%2522%2520)

**DB2 Schema Configuration**
Make sure that your WAS configuration is properly defining the appropriate *schema name* that you used in the steps above; the schema name is passed to the JDBC driver using the **currentSchema** property. The following documentation might be helpful as well:

- [Configuring DB2 on WAS Liberty profile](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_db2_manually.html&resultof=%2522%2563%2575%2572%2572%2565%256e%2574%2553%2563%2568%2565%256d%2561%2522%2520%2522%2563%2575%2572%2572%2565%256e%2574%2573%2563%2568%2565%256d%2561%2522%2520)
- [Configuring DB2 on WAS Standard profile](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_db2_manually.html&resultof=%2522%2557%2552%254b%2553%2543%2548%254d%2522%2520%2522%2577%2572%256b%2573%2563%2568%256d%2522%2520)
- [DB2 Cheat Sheet](http://dublintech.blogspot.com/2011/10/db2-cheat-sheet.html) (how to list the current DB2 schema names)
- [DB2 schema qualifiers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_schemaqualifiers.htm)

I hope this will help you get past this problem.

Comment: I dont see any table except WORKLIGHT_VERSION under WRKSCHM schema of WRKLGHT database.I think its a configuration issue.and Im not able to figure it out.Please suggest if anything is missing

Comment: Thanks eabe..i have created the database tables explictly which were under IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\databases\create-worklight-db2.sql and create-worklightreports-db2.sql.Solved the issue.

Comment: Hello @user2967626, I am glad that you were able to get past that issue. If you think my response answered properly to your question, then please consider flagging this question as "answered".